# decode Base64 string in hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi

I have a need to decode some base 64 string in java script server based in Hapi library
In [link](https://github.com/hapijs/b64/blob/master/README.md) I found that Hapi support base64 encode/decode but I can not find any example for how to use the relevant library.
Does anyone has a good example?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Comment: Ashish Modi, no, I can not, I just needed a sample for how to decode a value using hapi library, as I specified in the question I did find it is possible to decode a value easily.
Brahma Dev, you provided a solution but this solution will be need to be maintained, tested and so on, using a library from HAPI would decrease the amount of test that will be written for the code.
Eventually I asked a friend and he provided a link to a the relevant documentation:
https://hapi.dev/family/b64/api/?v=5.0.0